# How to filter out items from JSON ObservableCollection so they do NOT display in the List?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am using a SearchBar and I can return some API JSON data to find company names and their stock symbols. This gets deserialized fine into an ObservableCollection and displayed in a ListView.

However, sometimes the results contain a stock symbol that has a "-" (dash) in it. I would like to somehow test each item in my ObservableCollection, and prevent any item that contains a "-" in the symbol name, and then exclude it from appearing in the Collection that is bound to the ListView.

Here is my SearchObject:

```
public class SearchObject
    {
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string securityName { get; set; }
        public string securityType { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string exchange { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my working JSON API code:

```
 vSearchSymbol = mySearchBar.Text;
 SearchUrl = string.Format("MY SEARCH API URL {0}", vSearchSymbol);

 // Activity indicator visibility ON
 activity_indicator.IsRunning = true;

 // Getting JSON data from the Web
 var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(SearchUrl);

 // Deserialize the JSON data from content
 var tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SearchObject>>(content);

 // After deserializing, we store our data in an ObservableCollection List called 'trends'
 ObservableCollection<SearchObject> trends = new ObservableCollection<SearchObject>(tr);

 // Bind the list to the ListView
 myList.ItemsSource = trends;

 // Check the number of Items in the Observable Collection
 int i = trends.Count;
 if (i > 0)
 {
  // If the list count is > 0 then stop activity indicator
  activity_indicator.IsRunning = false;
  }
```

What would be the best way to eliminate any SearchObject item whose symbol contains a "-" from being included in the ObservableCollection? In other words, I do NOT want any items with a symbol that contains a dash to show up in the ListView.

Any guidance on the proper syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might also be looking for a collectionview. A way to bind a view around a observablecollection. That way, as data dynamically changes, the view always stays in sync. Create the observablecollection. Create a view around it with the filter logic. Then bind the view to the datasource. But if @AnuViswan answer fits your need, it is better / thinner. http://jacobmsaylor.com/filter-an-observablecollection-with-a-collectionview-in-c/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly. An easier approach would be to filter out the SearchObjects before creating the ObservableCollection using LINQ. For example,

```
 ObservableCollection<SearchObject> trends = new ObservableCollection<SearchObject>( tr.Where(x=>!x.symbol.Contains("-")));
```

Now your ObservableCollection would contains items which does not have a symbol that has a "-" character".

Comment: @TamusJRoyce am not quite sure if the OP has mentioned the "-" character would be at the beginning of  symbol. Did i miss something ?

Comment: Yes! This absolutely works. I see what you are doing with the testing logic. I just wasn't sure if some type of logic like this could be inserted at the moment I am creating the ObservableCollection, or if it had to run afterward. Thank you so much for your great answer.